# How to Sorting/Searching IP Address in datatable Using Listjs Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatable, listjs

Im looking for a way to searching an IP Address in the table rows using Listjs

My datatable was not containt IP Address table i just added it manully perfectly like customer, phone, email, Etc

and it works fine but when i type dots between number example we have ip address 127.0.0.1 if search for 127. it say No Result Found but when i type 127 with no dot it give me the three number of the ip but after adding the dot to complete the ip address says No Result Found i need to searching for full ip address i searching alot in google for the solution i just cannot figure it as im not good in javascrite

listjs.init.js

```js
var customerList, checkAll = document.getElementById("checkAll"),
    perPage = (checkAll && (checkAll.onclick = function() {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-all input[type="checkbox"]');
        1 == checkAll.checked ? Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {
            e.checked = !0, e.closest("tr").classList.add("table-active")
        }) : Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {
            e.checked = !1, e.closest("tr").classList.remove("table-active")
        })
    }), 8),
    editlist = !1,
    options = {
        valueNames: ["id", "customer_name", "ip_address", "email", "date", "phone", "status"],
        page: perPage,
        pagination: !0,
        plugins: [ListPagination({
            left: 2,
            right: 2
        })]
    };
document.getElementById("customerList") && (customerList = new List("customerList", options).on("updated", function(e) {
    0 == e.matchingItems.length ? document.getElementsByClassName("noresult")[0].style.display = "block" : document.getElementsByClassName("noresult")[0].style.display = "none";
    var t = 1 == e.i,
        a = e.i > e.matchingItems.length - e.page;
    document.querySelector(".pagination-prev.disabled") && document.querySelector(".pagination-prev.disabled").classList.remove("disabled"), document.querySelector(".pagination-next.disabled") && document.querySelector(".pagination-next.disabled").classList.remove("disabled"), t && document.querySelector(".pagination-prev").classList.add("disabled"), a && document.querySelector(".pagination-next").classList.add("disabled"), e.matchingItems.length <= perPage ? document.querySelector(".pagination-wrap").style.display = "none" : document.querySelector(".pagination-wrap").style.display = "flex", e.matchingItems.length == perPage && document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination").firstElementChild.children[0].click(), 0 < e.matchingItems.length ? document.getElementsByClassName("noresult")[0].style.display = "none" : document.getElementsByClassName("noresult")[0].style.display = "block"
}));
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhttp.onload = function() {
    var e = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Array.from(e).forEach(e => {
        customerList.add({
            id: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fw-medium link-primary">#VZ' + e.id + "</a>",
            customer_name: e.customer_name,
            ip_address: e.ip_address,
            email: e.email,
            date: e.date,
            phone: e.phone,
            status: isStatus(e.status)
        }), customerList.sort("id", {
            order: "desc"
        }), refreshCallbacks()
    }), customerList.remove("id", '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fw-medium link-primary">#VZ2101</a>')
}, xhttp.open("GET", "assets/json/table-customer-list.json"), xhttp.send();
var isValue = (isCount = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(customerList.items.slice(-1)[0]._values.id, "text/html")).body.firstElementChild.innerHTML,
    idField = document.getElementById("id-field"),
    customerNameField = document.getElementById("customername-field"),
    ipField = document.getElementById("ipaddress-field"),
    emailField = document.getElementById("email-field"),
    dateField = document.getElementById("date-field"),
    phoneField = document.getElementById("phone-field"),
    statusField = document.getElementById("status-field"),
    addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn"),
    editBtn = document.getElementById("edit-btn"),
    removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("remove-item-btn"),
    editBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-item-btn");

function filterContact(e) {
    var t = e;
    customerList.filter(function(e) {
        e = (matchData = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(e.values().status, "text/html")).body.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
        return "All" == e || "All" == t || e == t
    }), customerList.update()
}

function updateList() {
    var a = document.querySelector("input[name=status]:checked").value;
    data = userList.filter(function(e) {
        var t = !1;
        return "All" == a ? t = !0 : (t = e.values().sts == a, console.log(t, "statusFilter")), t
    }), userList.update()
}
refreshCallbacks(), document.getElementById("showModal") && (document.getElementById("showModal").addEventListener("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    e.relatedTarget.classList.contains("edit-item-btn") ? (document.getElementById("exampleModalLabel").innerHTML = "Edit Customer", document.getElementById("showModal").querySelector(".modal-footer").style.display = "block", document.getElementById("add-btn").innerHTML = "Update") : e.relatedTarget.classList.contains("add-btn") ? (document.getElementById("exampleModalLabel").innerHTML = "Add Customer", document.getElementById("showModal").querySelector(".modal-footer").style.display = "block", document.getElementById("add-btn").innerHTML = "Add Customer") : (document.getElementById("exampleModalLabel").innerHTML = "List Customer", document.getElementById("showModal").querySelector(".modal-footer").style.display = "none")
}), ischeckboxcheck(), document.getElementById("showModal").addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    clearFields()
})), document.querySelector("#customerList").addEventListener("click", function() {
    ischeckboxcheck()
});
var table = document.getElementById("customerTable"),
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    trlist = table.querySelectorAll(".list tr"),
    count = 11,
    forms = document.querySelectorAll(".tablelist-form"),
    statusVal = (Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function(a) {
        a.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            var t;
            a.checkValidity() ? (e.preventDefault(), "" === customerNameField.value || "" === ipField.value || "" === emailField.value || "" === dateField.value || "" === phoneField.value || editlist ? "" !== customerNameField.value && "" !== emailField.value && "" !== dateField.value && "" !== phoneField.value && editlist && (t = customerList.get({
                id: idField.value
            }), Array.from(t).forEach(function(e) {
                (isid = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(e._values.id, "text/html")).body.firstElementChild.innerHTML == itemId && e.values({
                    id: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fw-medium link-primary">' + idField.value + "</a>",
                    customer_name: customerNameField.value,
                    ip_address: ipField.value,
                    email: emailField.value,
                    date: dateField.value,
                    phone: phoneField.value,
                    status: isStatus(statusField.value)
                })
            }), document.getElementById("close-modal").click(), clearFields(), Swal.fire({
                position: "center",
                icon: "success",
                title: "Customer updated Successfully!",
                showConfirmButton: !1,
                timer: 2e3,
                showCloseButton: !0
            })) : (customerList.add({
                id: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fw-medium link-primary">#VZ' + count + "</a>",
                customer_name: customerNameField.value,
                ip_address: ipField.value,
                email: emailField.value,
                date: dateField.value,
                phone: phoneField.value,
                status: isStatus(statusField.value)
            }), customerList.sort("id", {
                order: "desc"
            }), document.getElementById("close-modal").click(), refreshCallbacks(), clearFields(), filterContact("All"), count++, Swal.fire({
                position: "center",
                icon: "success",
                title: "Customer inserted successfully!",
                showConfirmButton: !1,
                timer: 2e3,
                showCloseButton: !0
            }))) : (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation())
        }, !1)
    }), new Choices(statusField));

function isStatus(e) {
    switch (e) {
        case "Active":
            return '<span class="badge badge-soft-success text-uppercase">' + e + "</span>";
        case "Block":
            return '<span class="badge badge-soft-danger text-uppercase">' + e + "</span>"
    }
}

function ischeckboxcheck() {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByName("checkAll")).forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.target.checked ? e.target.closest("tr").classList.add("table-active") : e.target.closest("tr").classList.remove("table-active")
        })
    })
}

function refreshCallbacks() {
    removeBtns && Array.from(removeBtns).forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.target.closest("tr").children[1].innerText, itemId = e.target.closest("tr").children[1].innerText;
            e = customerList.get({
                id: itemId
            });
            Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {
                var t = (deleteid = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(e._values.id, "text/html")).body.firstElementChild;
                deleteid.body.firstElementChild.innerHTML == itemId && document.getElementById("delete-record").addEventListener("click", function() {
                    customerList.remove("id", t.outerHTML), document.getElementById("deleteRecordModal").click()
                })
            })
        })
    }), editBtns && Array.from(editBtns).forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.target.closest("tr").children[1].innerText, itemId = e.target.closest("tr").children[1].innerText;
            e = customerList.get({
                id: itemId
            });
            Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {
                var t = (isid = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(e._values.id, "text/html")).body.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
                t == itemId && (editlist = !0, idField.value = t, customerNameField.value = e._values.customer_name, ipield.value = e._values.ip_address, emailField.value = e._values.email, dateField.value = e._values.date, phoneField.value = e._values.phone, statusVal && statusVal.destroy(), statusVal = new Choices(statusField), t = (val = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(e._values.status, "text/html")).body.firstElementChild.innerHTML, statusVal.setChoiceByValue(t), flatpickr("#date-field", {
                    dateFormat: "d M, Y",
                    defaultDate: e._values.date
                }))
            })
        })
    })
}

function clearFields() {
    customerNameField.value = "", ipField.value = "", emailField.value = "", dateField.value = "", phoneField.value = ""
}

function deleteMultiple() {
    ids_array = [];
    var e = document.getElementsByName("chk_child");
    if (Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {
            1 == e.checked && (e = e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".id a").innerHTML, ids_array.push(e))
        }), "undefined" != typeof ids_array && 0 < ids_array.length) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) return !1;
        Array.from(ids_array).forEach(function(e) {
            customerList.remove("id", `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fw-medium link-primary">${e}</a>`)
        }), document.getElementById("checkAll").checked = !1
    } else Swal.fire({
        title: "Please select at least one checkbox",
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-info",
        buttonsStyling: !1,
        showCloseButton: !0
    })
}
document.querySelector(".pagination-next") && document.querySelector(".pagination-next").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination") && document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination").querySelector(".active") && document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination").querySelector(".active").nextElementSibling.children[0].click()
}), document.querySelector(".pagination-prev") && document.querySelector(".pagination-prev").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination") && document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination").querySelector(".active") && document.querySelector(".pagination.listjs-pagination").querySelector(".active").previousSibling.children[0].click()
});
var attroptions = {
        valueNames: ["name", "born", {
            data: ["id"]
        }, {
            attr: "src",
            name: "image"
        }, {
            attr: "href",
            name: "link"
        }, {
            attr: "data-timestamp",
            name: "timestamp"
        }]
    },
    attrList = new List("users", attroptions),
    existOptionsList = (attrList.add({
        name: "Leia",
        born: "1954",
        image: "assets/images/users/avatar-5.jpg",
        id: 5,
        timestamp: "67893"
    }), {
        valueNames: ["contact-name", "contact-message"]
    }),
    existList = new List("contact-existing-list", existOptionsList),
    fuzzySearchList = new List("fuzzysearch-list", {
        valueNames: ["name"]
    }),
    paginationList = new List("pagination-list", {
        valueNames: ["pagi-list"],
        page: 3,
        pagination: !0
    });
```

Comment: The question has over 200 lines of code in it. What is the smallest amount of code and data you can show us, which is easy for us to copy and run, and which clearly demonstrates the specific problem you are trying to solve? See [mre].

Comment: sorry for putting all the code as im beginner in javascript i really  dont know which part who is reponse for sorting i think javascript coders would figure which line is response for sorting i can understand thats this is a bit hard but i just cant figure which part to post

Comment: My suggestion: Start with no code at all. Add a [basic example](https://listjs.com/docs/) - make sure you understand it. Then introduce some [searching logic](https://listjs.com/docs/search-sort/). Enhance this code, maybe by adding [fuzzy search](https://listjs.com/examples/fuzzy-search/) if that is what you want to use. Take JavaScript tutorials to help you understand any syntax which may be confusing. Use SO to research any initial questions you may have. Compare what you have with the code in this question.